# I'm using brownie for testing contracts but its stuck like that in the image

Tags: wallets, python, brownie, test

I made a project folder using brownie. I can deploy the contract from the scripts folder but when I test it it's stuck I can't find anything that solves the problem.

[image]

Comment: Hey! It seems that there is no image in your post. You can edit it and add the image so that we can actually see the problem. Meanwhile, are you sure that the problem is not an infinite loop in the contract?

Comment: @Kostiantyn Kurbatskyi
I just uninstalled and reinstalled brownie. it works now. sorry for the late reply thank you for showing concern.